# Azure RemoteApp endpoints

Tags: azure, port-forwarding, remoteapp

I want to use Azure RemoteApp, but my application needs to have custom ports forwarded to it. When setting up the virtual machine, I created endpoints and those where working on the VM. After creating a template image from that machine, it lost the endpoints.

Question: is it possible to use Azure RemoteApp with custom endpoints? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that the answer to this is no. Endpoints are attached to the actual virtual machines (or load balancers if attached to a VNet), not the OS image, so when you move it over the RemoteApp and new VM's (RemoteApp sits on top of IaaS VM's that  you don't control) are created to host it then they would not have any endpoints configured, and there's no way to create them.